# Iframe Close - Button href

Tags: html, iframe, button

I actually make a homepage. My login-area is in an Iframe, here´s my code:

```
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){           

        $(".example7").colorbox({width:"85,5%", height:"85%",iframe:true});

    });
```

and

```
 <a href="http://www.google.at"><button>Klick</button></a>
```

My problem is, that I want the new link not to open in the iframe-window. 
How can I do that?

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.at" target="_parent"><button>Klick</button></a> can you try this.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution. Great!

Comment: Thanks Harald, if so please set my answer up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>` will open the link in a new page.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a#attr-target